# Appending update date one after the another in EDW_UPDATE_NOTE column

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have a scenario where we are trying to Append the data stored in a varchar column called EDW_UPDATE_NOTE, The data is stored in the column like the following format 'PWC mapping name- session start 12/10/2014 12:40:54' so when there is an update for this row for example, today '13-05-2020' then I want the data to get Updated as 'PWC mapping name - session start 05/13/2020 22:57:45|PWC mapping name - session start 12/10/2014 12:40:54' so that we can track that the data got updated first on 12/10/2014 and again it got updated on 05/13/2020.

NOTE: we are using Informatica for loading the tables and the current logic is written as mentioned below in the expression transformation 'PWC mapping '||$$PWC_MAPPING_NAME ||'- session start '||TO_CHAR(sysdate,'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') ||'|'|| edw_update_note

but every time when an update is done the data gets updated as "PWC mapping name- session start 05/13/2020 22:57:45|PWC mapping name - session start 05/13/2020 22:57:44" both shows the same date and time and we are not able to Append the old date value concatenated with the latest updated date value.

Comment: This is very quickly going to get out of hand and be unusable from a querying sense. Do not store multiple row data in a single row; it always leads to trouble. At the very least, consider using XML or JSON so you have built in parsing, but really you should do this as a separate history table, or leverage whatever built in options for auditing as suits your business requirements

Comment: Also, i didn't understand *both shows the same date and time* and `05/13/2020 22:57:45 ... 05/13/2020 22:57:44` - these are not the "same" data and time

Comment: You need to pickup old value concat with new value and store again.Do a lookup into the target tale, pickup the EDW_UPDATE_NOTE and then concat it with 'PWC mapping '||$$PWC_MAPPING_NAME ||'- session start '||TO_CHAR(sysdate,'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') in the mapping.